# ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Area support

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm looking for a safe and functionally way to implement areas in MVC 1.0. My application is very big, with something about 150 controllers and 200 views, and at now we have to stay on the MVC 1.0, so porting to 2.0 is not an option..

I took a look in the phil haack solution but it doesn't work for typed views, and I found too some other solutions, but all of them are poorly implementation with lack of something.

There's a fully functionally implementation on the net?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Trivial porting to 2 is fairly low-effort, IIRC - I think we only hit problems where we enumerated ValueProviders, a few updates to custom controls where the MVC Html helper now returns MvcHtmlString not String, and updating some JSON handlers with JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet as necessary. Everything else just works. Is it really better to hack areas into 1 rather than update to 2?

Comment: That's true.. that's a good question, sure it's better to update to 2 than implement this feature in 1, but this could not be so fine and so easy with restrictions of version and platform. If the project responsible he won't to upgrade, there's nothing to do unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

Is this your issue:

http://lukesampson.com/post/303515912/asp-net-mvc-1-0-areas

Comment: I need to test this solution, but I think if it solve the issue, the it will be what I was looking for! Is still possible to split pages and content in area and leave other application part in the default folder structure?

Comment: I'm not sure. I have seen Areas implemented in v1.0 before, but to be honest I don't know the details of the implementation.